# Working with Temp Tables and Stored Procedure to get some data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a project, the aim is to get result analysed as shown in image:[image]

However, My table looks like this in the image here:

[image]

Now, I have search using my title in this question to see how to achieve the result I showed in image 1 using my table in image 2 to generate a sql procedure as stated here but I am stuck and I need your help.

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[getScoreClassificationbySchools]
@NameofSchool nvarchar(31), @levelName nvarchar(5)
as 
Begin
create table #A(LevelNames varchar(50), SchoolSubject varchar (50))
create table #B(LevelNames varchar(50), TotalNostudent int, SchoolSubjectt varchar (50))
create table #C(LevelNames varchar(50), ScoreClassDistinction varchar (10), SchoolSubject varchar (50))
create table #D(LevelNames varchar(50), ScoreClassCredit varchar (10), SchoolSubject varchar (50))
create table #E(LevelNames varchar(50), ScoreClassPass varchar (10), SchoolSubject varchar (50))
create table #F(LevelNames varchar(50), ScoreClassFail varchar (10), SchoolSubject varchar (50))

insert into #A(LevelNames, SchoolSubject)
select distinct LevelName,  Subject from tb_schlist where @levelName =LevelName AND @NameofSchool = SchoolName 

insert into #B(LevelNames, TotalNostudent,SchoolSubjectt)
select distinct LevelName, count (LevelName) as TotalNoOfStudent, Subject from tb_schlist where @levelName =LevelName AND @NameofSchool = SchoolName 

insert into #C(LevelNames, ScoreClassDistinction, SchoolSubject)
select distinct LevelName, Grades, Subject from tb_schlist where  @levelName =LevelName and @NameofSchool = SchoolName and Grades='A1'

insert into #D(LevelNames, ScoreClassCredit, SchoolSubject)
select distinct LevelName, Grades, Subject from tb_schlist where @levelName =LevelName and @NameofSchool = SchoolName and Grades='B2'

insert into #E(LevelNames, ScoreClassPass, SchoolSubject)
select distinct LevelName, Grades, Subject from tb_schlist where  @levelName =LevelName and @NameofSchool = SchoolName and Grades='B3'

insert into #F(LevelNames, ScoreClassFail, SchoolSubject)
select distinct LevelName, Grades, Subject from tb_schlist where  @levelName =LevelName and @NameofSchool = SchoolName and Grades='C4'

SELECT t1.lnames , t2.SchoolSubject, t3.ScoreClassDistinction, t4.ScoreClassCredit, t5.ScoreClassPass, t6.ScoreClassFail from #A t1 join #B t2 on t1.LevelNameS = t2.LevelNames join #C t3 join #D t4 on t3.LevelNames = t4.LevelNames join #E t5 join #F t6  on t5.LevelNames = t6.LevelNames
```

Comment: "I am stuck and I need your help" - you'll have to be more specific than that. What exact problem is it that you're stuck on? And how are you supposed to get the result from the input you've given?

Comment: please be specific when ask question. It will help community to answer your question, it will be better for you as well as community.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
select SUBJECT, 
[A1]+[B2]+[B3]+[C4]+[C5]+[C6] + [D7]+ [E8] + [F9] 
As TotalNoOfStudentsThatSat,
[A1],[B2],[B3],[C4],[C5],[C6] ,
 [A1]+[B2]+[B3]+[C4]+[C5]+[C6] AS [A1-C6]
 , [D7],[E8],[D7]+ [E8] AS [D7-E8]
 , [F9] from marks 
 pivot (
   count(grade) 
   for grade in ([A1],[B2],[B3],[C4],[C5],[C6],[D7],[E8],[F9])
 )PVT
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0998c/16)

Comment: Thank you @Ravi. This is helpful. I have modified it to look like this   'select distinct sbjname, Count ([lname]) As TotalNoOfStudentsThatSat, ([A1],[B2],[B3],[C4],[C5],[C6]
,[A1]+[B2]+[B3]+[C4]+[C5]+[C6] AS [A1-C6],
[D7],[E8],[D7]+ [E8] AS [D7-E8],
[F9] from tb_schlist 
pivot
(count(ScoreClassify)
 for ScoreClassify in ([A1],[B2],[B3],[C4],[C5],[C6],[D7],[E8],[F9]) 
 )PVT where SchoolName='Girls Junior High School' ' but I don't know how to add the percentage as shown in the image  [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftv244yfmf9vagi/proposedResultAnalysis.png